# Multiple Header rows in JqGrid

Tags: jqgrid, header, row

Presently we are able to get this as output by binding jQgrid to serialized JSON from server Side.

[image]

But Can I get the following output.?

[image]

Comment: I don't know why you want to show headers again. if column headers are same then just a make grouping like [this](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/grouping/multiple_columns_header/index.html)

Comment: Hi, Its actually the client requirement , they sent us an image with multiple header rows. Ours is huge Business Intelligence project with crores of records. I just wanted to know if there is feasibility to do as asked?? Thanks.

Comment: The Reason I mentioned about our project is that we do grouping from SP

Comment: @Ganesh: jqGrid are based on HTML `<table>` which have no support for repeating of column headers after some rows of data. You should explain your customers the fact. I suppose that your problem have nothing common with the picture which you posted. For example you could use large grid without paging, which require the user scroll below to the next page and don't see the column headers.

Comment: @Ganesh: Another typical example which I know is the usage if large number of columns of the same type like checkboxes. It's difficult to identify the columns headers in the case, but one can set custom **tooltip** on such columns. Then hovering on the call of the grid will display the column header over every checkbox. In any way your current requirement in the form which you posted seems to have less sense and can't be implemented. You should post **more realistic** example and to change the requirement so that the customer solves the original problem, but in *another way*.

Comment: @Oleg: I don't know but may be they are getting confused with their own data, and required that header to act as a separator. We did suggest an alternative and said the current requirement is infeasible. I just wanted to confirm. on the other hand, because we do everything from SP including the sorting functionality. I thought it were possible to do this by adding extra header row in the Data Set received in code behind - that is only if they insist. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: @Ganesh: You are welcome!

Comment: hello @Ganesh: i have similar client requirement for multiple header rows. Wanted to know if you were able to achieve this? If yes, could you please share your approach? thank you.

Comment: Hi @ user902490......... No, we didn't solve it, we convinced the client.